# angular 2 routing inject into router-outlet not working

Tags: routes, angular, router

I'm trying to get my head wrap around this routing concept but having trouble understanding how  works.

Currently I have a @routes that load a component with a '/' path. This should load into the  as soon as the page render. What i'm have trouble with is.. my component only load if there's a [routerLink] present in the html template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `    
  <h1>Component Router</h1>
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center']">Crisis Center</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})

@Routes([
  {path: '/', component: CoreComponent}
])

***core.component**

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes , RouterOutletMap} from '@angular/router';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { SideBarComponent} from './sidebar/sidebar.component';


@Component({
    template: `<side-bar></side-bar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [SideBarComponent]

})

export class CoreComponent{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue in the new router that will be fixed. No router instance will be created at all if there is no `routerLink`. Alternatively you can inject the router into the root component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You've mentioned on the other thread to inject "Router" in AppComponent. Did you run to an " cannot resolve all param for Router " error?

Comment: You are importing from `import { Routes , RouterOutletMap} from '@angular/router';` **and** `import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';`. You'll need to decide for only one of them. These two are not compatible in any way.

Comment: I got the error using using @angular/router, I also tried using @angular/router-deprecate and got the same thing. I'm curious what version you are on. I'm currently using  "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1".

Comment: Your code above imports from both at the same time - which is invalid in any way. `router-deprecated` is the same router as the one shipped in beta versions. `router` is the "new" router which currently lacks some basic features.